# Why does Node block the streamed file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, video-streaming, file-descriptor

I am writing a function that sends a video file via stream to the client. It works correctly except that in each request it opens a file descriptor but never closes it. This means that these files cannot be deleted later since they are blocked by the Node process.

This is the function that causes this situation:

```
exports.stream = (req, res, next) => {
    const range = req.headers.range;
    const volumeName = req.query.volume;
    const folderPath = req.query.folder;
    const fileName = req.query.file;
    if (!range) return res.sendStatus(416);
    try {
        let volume = Services.volumes.get.byName(volumeName);
        let path = volume.location + folderPath + fileName;
        let pathExists = Services.files.get.exists(path);
        if (!pathExists) return res.status(404).send('unable to stream file, path not exists');
        
        let stats = fs.statSync(path);
        if (!stats.isFile()) {
            return res.status(400).send('requested path is not a file: ' + path);
        }
        const fileSize = stats.size;

        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;
        let chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
        const maxChunk = 1024 * 1024;
        if (chunksize > maxChunk) {
            end = start + maxChunk - 1;
            chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
        }

        res.writeHead(206, {
            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': chunksize,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        });

        let stream = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end, autoClose: true});
        stream.on('open', function () {
            stream.pipe(res);
        });
        stream.on('error', function (err) {
            res.end(err);
        });
        stream.on('close', function () {
            stream.destroy();
        });
    } catch (e) {
        next(new Error('unable to stream path: ' + e));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to prevent streams from being left open.

- on the one hand, I had to **restrict** the amount of information to send in each request (AKA **chunksize**).
- on the other hand I have used **[pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback)** instead of **pipe**. In theory both things are the same but in practice they work differently. [This link](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/) has served me as a starting point.

The code is as follows (we still need to put it nice):

```
exports.stream = ({config}) => (req, res, next) => {
    let volumeName = req.query.volume;
    let folderPath = req.query.folder;
    let fileName = req.query.file;
    try {
        let volume = Services.volumes.get.byName(volumeName);
        let path = volume.location + folderPath + fileName;
        let exists = Services.files.get.exists(path);
        if (!exists) {
            return res.status(404).send('unable to stream file, path not exists');
        }

        let stats = fs.statSync(path);
        if (!stats.isFile()) {
            return res.status(400).send('requested path is not a file: ' + path);
        }

        const fileSize = stats.size;
        let maxchunksize = 1024 * 1024;
        let headers = {};
        let readable;

        if (req.headers['range']) {
            const range = req.headers.range;
            const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            let start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            let end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;
            let chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
            if (start > end || start < 0 || end > fileSize - 1) {
                headers['Content-Range'] = '*/' + fileSize;
                res.writeHead(416, headers);
                return res.end();
            }
            if (chunksize > maxchunksize) {
                end = start + maxchunksize - 1;
                chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
            }
            headers['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes';
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4';
            headers['Content-Range'] = 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + fileSize;
            headers['Content-Length'] = chunksize;
            res.writeHead(206, headers);
            readable = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end, autoClose: true});

        } else {
            headers['Content-Length'] = fileSize;
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4';
            res.writeHead(200, headers);
            readable = fs.createReadStream(path);
        }

        stream.pipeline(readable, res, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        next(new Error('unable to stream path: ' + e));
    }
};
```